# How do I calculate rumple index for grid plots (e.g.30x30m) from canopy height model (res 1m) using lidR?

Tags: r, raster, lidr

I want to calculate rumple index using rumple_index() function (lidR package) from chm (raster with res 1m). Specifically, I want calculate it for grid plots, e.g. different empty raster (res 30x30m). I expect raster (30x30m) output with rumple index value in each cell.

rumple_index(chm) – this gives me value for entire chm, but I don't know how to get result for another raster (30x30m) output with rumple index in each cell.

Comment: It is not possible. You must write your own code. lidR is designed to process point clouds not rasters

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation.